# encode url (or replace string / regex) in mongodb via node, mongoose

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to do some operations on one collection and at the end store the result in another collection. Will be doing this via aggregation. Platform is node, mongoose, mongodb.

One of the required operations which I can't figure out is urlEncoding a particular field. The field can be constrained to only contain alphabets, numbers and spaces, so basically **what I need to do is convert spaces to %20**

Note that I need to do this while using node. I am pretty new in node, mongoose, mongodb, etc, so I'm not sure If I can run custom javascript code from node into mongoose or if that will be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `encodeURIComponent()` to url encode a string in javascript.

You could do this on all field values *before* storing them, but only if you're sure you'll never need the original value (the converse method, `decodeuricomponent()` may not always honor things such as case).

Alternatively, you could store the value 'as is', and use `encodeURIComponent()` when retrieving the value.

Comment: The values will be created during the aggregation process. So can't encode while storing. During aggregation, multiple values need to combine to form a url, so can't use encodeURIComponent afterwards either. Unless I reform my whole codebase and database schema, which I'd rather not do.